# sed: matched pattern to end of previous line

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I'm trying to replace the carriage return to the end of the previous line.
^M is a carriage return.

**Example:**

```
hello 
hello 1^M 
hello 2^M 
hello 3^M
hello 4^M
hello 5^M
hello 6
```

**What I need:**

```
hello
hello 1 hello 2 hello 3 hello 4 hello 5
hello 6
```

I want all ^M replace to end of previous line without ^M .
Do you have any idea. How to replace it?

This is my command:

```
sed -i 's/^M//g' filtest.txt
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' filtest.txt
```

The result:

```
hellohello 1hello 2hello 3hello 4hello 5hello 6
```

Thanks for helps! :)

Comment: How are you supposed to tell from the input what output you want here? Or do you have to hard-code that since there's no way to tell?

Comment: Why do you expect only the first `^M` getting replaced?

Comment: Whats the algorithm that dictates that the `\r\n` at the end of `hello5` is to only get it's `\r` removed and it's `\n` remains while the preceding 4 lines get their full `\r\n` removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what it looks like you want, using GNU awk for multi-char RS, and the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ gawk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{
    match($0,/\r.*\r/,a)
    gsub(/\r(\n|$)/,"",a[0])
    print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) a[0] substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}' file
hello 
hello 1hello 2hello 3hello 4hello 5
hello 6
```